# How to remove special character or unwanted symbols from the file written JSON format in C# UNity?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

The JSON format when I read after writing is as follows

```html
�[{"SaveValues":[{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-5.12429666519165,"y":4.792403697967529},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":1},{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-4.788785934448242,"y":-3.4373996257781984},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":1}],"NoteValues":[{"movenumber":1,"notemsg":"Move One"}]},{"SaveValues":[{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-5.12429666519165,"y":4.792403697967529},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2},{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-4.788785934448242,"y":-3.4373996257781984},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2},{"id":2,"allposition":{"x":5.185188293457031,"y":4.803859233856201},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2},{"id":2,"allposition":{"x":5.154441833496094,"y":-4.023111343383789},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2}],"NoteValues":[{"movenumber":2,"notemsg":"Move Two"}]}]
```

The code I use for saving to JSON format is given below.

```
 ListContainer container = new ListContainer(getAlldata,playerNotes);

    var temp = container;
    //--Adding data in container into List<string> jsonstring
    jsonstring.Add(JsonUtility.ToJson(temp));

 //--Combing list of string into a single string
    string jsons = "[" +string.Join(",", jsonstring)+"]";

    //Writing into a JSON file in the persistent path
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream( Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath , savedName+".json"), FileMode.Create))
    {
        BinaryWriter filewriter = new BinaryWriter(fs);

        filewriter.Write(jsons);
        fs.Close();

    }
```

Here I am looking to remove the special character that came at the starting point of the JSON format.
I am trying to read the JSON by using the following code

```
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename, FileMode.Open))
        {


            fs.Dispose();
            string dataAsJson = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filename));
            Debug.Log("DataJsonRead - - -" + dataAsJson);

        }
```

I am getting an error - ArgumentException: JSON parse error: Invalid value.
How to remove that special or unwanted symbol from the starting ?I think it is something to do with writing the file into the directory.While trying to save with other methods I did not find any character or symbols.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a `BinaryWriter`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

� is the Unicode Replacement character, emitted when there's an attempt to read text as if they were encoded with a single-byte codepage using the *wrong* codepage. It's not a BOM - `File.ReadAllText` would recognize it and use it to load the rest of the file using the correct encoding. This means there's garbage at the start.

The problem is caused by the inappropriate use of `BinaryWriter`. That class is used to write *fields* of primitive types in a binary format to a stream. For variable length types like stings, the first byte(s) contain the field length.

This code :

```
using var ms=new MemoryStream();
using( BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(ms))
{  
  writer.Write(new String('0',3));        
}

var b=ms.ToArray();
```

Produces

```
3, 48,48,48
```

Use `StreamWriter` or `File.WriteAllText` instead. The default encoding used is UTF8 so there's no need to specify an encoding or try to change anything :

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream( Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath , savedName+".json"), FileMode.Create))
using(var writer=new StreamWriter(fs))
{
        writer.Write(jsons);
}
```

or

```
var path=Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath , savedName+".json")
using(var writer=new StreamWriter(path))
{
        writer.Write(jsons);
}
```

Comment: There was something wrong with the JSON saving process,finally got it.I asked same question some time in Unity forum I got a reply it is a BOM file.Gr8 answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

first add this to your .cs file

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

then we can do this with *RegEx* as follows.

```
varName = Regex.Replace(SaveValues, "[-*]", "");
```

This will look for the `-` symbol and remove it from your string.
Hope this helps.

Comment: That looks for `-` and `*`.